# Firestore: Query Array of DocumentReference's to populate Recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

My database is structured such that I have a *users* collection filled with *user* documents, each having a field that is an array of `DocumentReferences` that exist in a collection at the same level as the *users* collection.

I need to retrieve this data and populate a RecyclerView upon completion of the queries. Currently, my dilemma is that I need to iterate over each `DocumentReference` and only initialize my RecyclerView when the final `onSuccessListener` executes. Is there a reliable way of doing this in Firestore?

Answer (score 0):

You can still initialize your `RecyclerView` before `onSuccessListener` and just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after adding the `item`

> To populate data from a `Collection` we can use a `for each` loop to iterate through the `Documents`

```
CollectionReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(USERS);


ref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot>task){
                         if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                         for(DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                          //query here
                          item.add(document);
                          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                         }
                         } else {
                         //fail getMessage
                         }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @gege. I'm aware of `notifyDataSetChanged()`. However, this does not look visually appealing since the data pops in - which means it could takes x amount of seconds for  data that should be there to appear. I want to load all of them before attempting to make the recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Starting with today (2018-08-13), according to the updated documentation regarding [array membership](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership), now it is possible to filter data based on array values using `whereArrayContains()` method. In yoiur case you should use:

```
CollectionReference usersRef = db.collection("users");
usersRef.whereArrayContains("DocumentReferences", SpecificDocumentReferences);
```

> This query returns every user document where the `DocumentReferences` field is an **array** that contains a specific document reference. If the array has multiple instances of the value you query on, the document is included in the results only once.